# MYSQL PHP Search Function INNER JOIN is not required

Tags: php, mysql, select, match, inner-join

I have a search query:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.name, 
       i.image_id, 
       MATCH(a.name, a.about, a.tags) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM table_1 a 
INNER JOIN image_table i ON a.id = i.field_id 
WHERE MATCH(a.name, a.about, a.tags) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE)!=0 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

The output of this query is quite simple, it retreives tuples that match against the fields name, about and tags. The output also gets a related image from another table using an INNER JOIN.

But if there is not an image, i.e. if a user doesn't upload an image (inserting it into the image table), the whole field is not flagged as a viable match and returned as a result.

> How can I change this query to get the tuple from table_1 even if the
>   image does not exist?

As I could just generate a default image for the matched tuple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Exactly @ColinMorelli thanks, just refreshed myself on the different types of joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.name, 
       i.image_id, 
       MATCH(a.name, a.about, a.tags) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM table_1 a 
LEFT JOIN image_table i ON a.id = i.field_id 
WHERE MATCH(a.name, a.about, a.tags) AGAINST ('%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE)!=0 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: I agree with the first change, the left join, but 'OR i.field_id IS NULL' returns all fields from the table

Comment: Of course. I did not notice that you match only against columns in your `table_1`.